# Rendering a component into an ExtJS grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, components, cellrenderer

I want to render a split button into a column in a grid to perform actions on each row. I can't seem to figure out how to build a custom cell renderer that will accomplish this.

Each cell will have the exact same split button, but will act on the id of the row the split button is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a custom renderer for the column, have a look at this example: http://techmix.net/blog/2010/11/25/add-button-to-extjs-gridpanel-cell-using-renderer/

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Congratz the link is not working and you where lazy  enough not to paste the most important idea, downvote.