# Add component in Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Hi i want add component in grid
i try to do this
[Rendering a component into an ExtJS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409629/rendering-a-component-into-an-extjs-grid)
but i saw in cell 
and button under grid

I use ExtJs 4

```
    columns:[
      {header:"test", dataIndex:'registrationDate', width:30, renderer:function (value, id, r) {
            var id = Ext.id();
            new Ext.Button({
                text:"1", handler:function (btn, e) {
                    // do whatever you want here
                }
            }).render(document.body, id);

            return('&lt;div id="' + id + '"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
        }}
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the buttons with click handler in the columns use the actioncolumn xtype.